# How to toggle transform transition upon click?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

https://codepen.io/pen/MoWLrZ

When you click the first time, it will show the animation of the two overlays. But on second click it, the two overlays just goes back on one swoop.

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickThis').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.overlay').toggleClass('extend');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you only have two `overlay` containers `grey` and `white`.
You might need to replace their `transition-delay` property if you want `two swoops` on the `second` click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickThis').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('.overlay.grey').hasClass('extend') === true) {
            $('.overlay.grey').css('transition-delay', '0.3s');
            $('.overlay.white').css('transition-delay', '0.1s');
        } else {
            $('.overlay.grey').css('transition-delay', '0.1s');
            $('.overlay.white').css('transition-delay', '0.3s');
        }
        $('.overlay').toggleClass('extend');
    });
});
```

This is because by the time you've click the `#clickThis` element, The `white` container is the current `container` that last show up because of the given delay you have given on your css (e.g `0.3s`).

Thus, on the `second` click, The `grey` container was already taking affect but its hidden behind the `white` container (Look at the z-index property)

Hope this helps for your case